# How to correctly handle UTF-8 strings in XCode Objective-C program with multiple inputs?

Tags: utf-8, nsstring

In a program, I am reading data from a pure text input file, some more data from a preference file (user input saved in a plist file) and finally strings from a localization file in my project.

When I display these files in some external editor (e.g. Sublime Text) using unicode, they are correct.

Basically, my program is taking data from the input file, adding some HTML enhancements and including contents from plist file and localization file. Then, I put the result in another text file.

When I have a look to the output file in that same editor, all strings coming from plist or localization are not correctly handled and I wonder to know what is wrong somewhere.

As an example, here is a line from the output file :

```
1 NOTE <div id="occu"><h4>Activit? professionnelle</h4><div style="background-color:#f3f3f3; padding:10px;">
```

"Activit? professionnelle" is coming from localization file . it should be displayed as shown in localization file

```
"OCCU" = "Activité professionnelle";
```

Here is another line from the output file :

```
2 CONT <table><tr><td><strong>T?oin(s) au d??</strong>: </td></tr><tr><td>Machin Truc, son cousin</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

"T?oin(s) au d??" should be displayed as shown in plist file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>description</key>
        <string>LIFE:Témoin(s) au décès</string>
        <key>private</key>
        <false/>
        <key>tag</key>
        <string>_WID</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

In the program, I use NSLocalizedString to access Localization file. Result is handled in a NSMutableString

```
        [sNote appendString: NSLocalizedString(occuTagLabel,occuTagLabel)];
```

Plist data are handled in a NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary, each containing an object instance of a class I have defined in the program. It is initialized as follow :

```
    NSMutableArray *tagTable;
    tagTable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: fName];
```

During debugging, XCode is displaying these strings as expected :

```
sNote   __NSCFString *  @"<div id=\"occu\"><h4>Activité professionnelle"    0x0000600000487180
```

but when I display any string coming from the input file (which are correctly displayed in the output file as well

```
value   __NSCFString *  @"Quelque part, DÃ©partement, Pays" 0x000060000049f1b0
```

I understand that strings from Plist or Localization are NOT interpreted as UTF-8

Does anyone could explain this unexpected behavior ? What should I do in order to have all strings interpreted as UTF-8

Comment: It's not clear what "when I display any string coming from the input file" means. What is "display" here? These look like things copied from the debugger perhaps (do not rely on the debugger to be correct)? Does this issue occur in any actual code? (Which code?) "I understand that strings from Plist or Localization are NOT interpreted as UTF-8." Why do you believe that? (It actually depends quite a lot; for example, localization files are often encoded in UTF-16, but that's not what you're seeing here.) It's unclear from your question what code you're using that demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: I understand that Debugger is not reliable but I have 3 sources for my data and all three are obviously correct when I display them in some text editor. But when I check the final result, only one is ok. When I have a look to some data from the two others in Debugger, I notice a true difference compared to data from the first one. The fact is that I do not have a correct result and I guess some strings are not properly handled

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The information you're giving here is very imprecise. For example, Unicode is not an encoding, so opening a file "using unicode" doesn't mean anything, and we have to guess at what you really mean and what you're actually looking at and not showing us. The concern seems to be with the output function, but you don't show the output function (what generates the "1 NOTE ..." string? Why do you believe it is correct at the time that you write it?) Why do you believe that plists and localization files are never UTF-8?

Comment: What encoding is your input file in? Are you certain that it is utf-8 (what makes you certain)? The `Ã©` looks a lot like you've used Latin-1 somewhere.

Comment: Your comments made me understand that, unlike what I believed, my program was handling latin-1 and not utf-8. I took the issue from the wrong end. I  then solved my problem. Thanks